# How do I uninstall these Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Today I tried to use profiler.firefox.com which is some webapp that Mozilla makes to help you profile webpages in Firefox.

I have a simple webpage I wanted to profile which just has a small script and almost no html. I captured a profile and then in the profiler UI if I click the Firefox 78 tab a the top it shows I have a bunch of extensions installed.

[image]

I never installed most of these extensions. I never installed a Wikipedia extension, nor Bing, nor Amazon, nor eBay, nor DuckDuckGo.

Checking the adds-on UI they don't show up there

[image]

How do I get rid of these extensions?

Answer (score 3):

#### I never installed a Wikipedia, Bing, Amazon, eBay, or DuckDuckGo extension

> How do I get rid of these extensions?

They are not extensions they are Search Engines. They are not being classified correctly by the profiler.

To remove them:

> 1. Open the Search panel in Firefox Options using one of these methods:
>
>    - Click the menu button and select <kbd>Options</kbd>. In the Options tab that opens, click on <kbd>Search</kbd> in the left pane.
>    - If you added the optional Search bar, click the <kbd>magnifying</kbd> <kbd>glass</kbd> on the Search bar and then
>      click <kbd>Change Search Settings</kbd>.
> 2. Under One-click search engines, click on the search engine you want to remove.
>
>    > [image]
> 3. Click the <kbd>Remove</kbd> button to take it off your list.

Source [Add or remove a search engine in Firefox | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox)

Comment: didn't work. I removed them as you show. They no longer show up in settings. They still show up in the profiler (yes, I quit firefox completely, checked they aren't listed in settings, then ran the profiler again).

Comment: Then `profiler.firefox.com` is broken ...

Comment: or they didn't really get uninstalled and are just marked as hidden/disabled. i mean come on!, the profiler, written by mozilla, is just asking the browser "what do you have installed?" and the browser is reporting what's installed. How is that a bug in profiler.firefox.com?

Comment: I'm seeing the same list, and I've had amazon and ebay at least disabled forever...  so yeah they're just sitting there "hidden", is my conclusion.